# Post file via mootools to php

Tags: file, mootools

I am using mootools framwork to built my website using php for coding. now I want to submit form via mootools which Contains basic html tags with file uploader. So, How can i send this file to '.php' page using mootools request?

Answer (score 0):

If the file uploader is a standard `<input type="file">` and it's contained between a `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`, you can just send the form via Javascript.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
</form>
```

```
$('myForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @lorenzo-s' answer, you may want to consider using [Mootools Request](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request), or perhaps even [Request.JSON](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.JSON), if you are returning JSON encoded data.

**Javascript**

```
var myRequest = new Request({          // This defines the AJAX call's parameters (url, callback function, etc)
    url: '/url/to/script.php',
    onSuccess: function(returnText) {
        console.log(returnText);
    }
});

myRequest.post({ foo: 'bar' });        // This makes the actual call, sending an object with one property: `foo`.
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot handle file uploads with Mootools Request.